# How to convert blob data sent from javascript to Django server for Speech Recognition module

Tags: python, django, speech-recognition

I want to record some audio on the client side using Javascript and send it to my Django Server
Here is my js code for recording and sending the data to the server.

```
function start_recording(){
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                .then(stream => {
                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                    console.log(mediaRecorder)
                    mediaRecorder.start();


                    const audioChunks = [];
                    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                    audioChunks.push(event.data);
                    });

                    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                    console.log("stop is called")
                    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);

                    });

                    //
                    
                    var stop_button =document.getElementById('stop_button');
                    stop_button.addEventListener('click',function(){
                        console.log(mediaRecorder,'stopped')
                        mediaRecorder.stop()


                    })
                });

            }
function GetAudio(audioBlob){
                console.log('>>>>>>>>get audioblob',audioBlob)
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

                var form = new FormData();
                form.append('audio', audioBlob);
                //console.log(wavfromblob)
                let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
                // var audio_base64;

                $.ajax({
                            url:"/get_sound/",
                            headers: {'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken},
                            type:'POST',
                            processData:false,
                            contentType:false,
                            //contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                            data:form,
                            //data:JSON.stringify({'hello':'hi','audio_base_64':audio_base64}),
                            error: function (request, status, error) {
                                alert(error);
                            }
                        }).done(function(response){
                            if(response=="true"){
                                console.log("true");
                                alert("data sent")
                            }else{
                                console.log("false");
                                alert("data was not recieved")
                                
             
                

                        
            }
```

here is my function code from views.py

```
def get_sound(request):
    print("get sound was called")
    if request.method == 'POST':

        print(request.FILES)
        audio_blob= request.FILES['audio']
        file_obj=io.BytesIO()
        file_obj.write(audio_blob.read())
        file_obj.seek(0)
        print(file_obj)
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

        with sr.AudioFile(file_obj) as source:
            print("loading")
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
            #print("Recording for 4 seconds")
            #recorded_audio = recognizer.listen(source, timeout=4)
            print("Done recording")

        # ''' Recorgnizing the Audio '''
        try:
            print("Recognizing the text")
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(
                    audio, 
                    language="en-US"
                )
            print("Decoded Text : {}".format(text))

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    return render(request,'get_sound.html')
```

It returns this error:
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format.

I have searched that wave module is used by AudioFile and it only supports the types given above(PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC)

How to I convert this wav data into pcm wav.Or is there any other way to send data from client to server?

EDIT:I was encoding the data into a base64 and then sending it,but that method didnt work.So I am sending the audio blob in javaascript Formdata and accepting it on the server with request.FILES.

Comment: name `audio_base64` can suggest that you send it as `base64` data - and it means you have to encode it in Python using module `base64` and functions like `base64.encode()` or `base64.b64encode()`

Comment: when I run it on Firefox then it sends audio as `Opus`, not `WAV`

Comment: [Media Recorder Save in WAV format across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191193/media-recorder-save-in-wav-format-across-browsers)