# An audio recorder work-around that doesn't use PortAudio for a streamlit webapp

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio, streamlit

I tried deploying my keyword-detector model using Streamlit. I initially used sounddevice for recording audio on streamlit app, which worked fine locally, but it threw an error when I tried deploying it on Heroku and Streamlit. Apparently, PortAudio is something one can't add to the requirements as it is not a python package. I've been stuck since then. I would really like to know if there's another library (other than sounddevice, Pyaudio) which doesn't use PortAudio or a webrtc that can allow my webapp to record user's audio.

Please find the link to the streamlit app [here](https://github.com/StaticJunkk/speech-to-text/blob/master/streamlitdep.py)
and the code I was using to record the audio

```
import sounddevice as sd
import os
from scipy.io.wavfile import write


def record(duration):
    fs = 44100  # Sample rate
    seconds = duration  # Duration of recording

    myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
    sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
    write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)
```

Comment: when you run it on server then it tries to use audio devices on server - not your local devices - but server doesn't need audio devices because nobody can access devices on server. You can't connect local microphone to server to record it. You can't connect local speakers to server to hear sound. You can't connect local camera to record video. You can't connect local monitor to see generated video or GUI windows (tkinter/PyQt,etc.), games (PyGame, etc.) You would have to use `JavaScript` to record voice by web browser and send it to server.

Comment: [Media Recorder Save in WAV format across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191193/media-recorder-save-in-wav-format-across-browsers), [Using the MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API)

Comment: try: https://github.com/whitphx/streamlit-webrtc

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on implementing a **custom component that enables recording audio from the client’s microphone in apps that are deployed on the web** ([Streamlit-Audio-Recorder](https://github.com/stefanrmmr/streamlit_audio_recorder)). This version of the component supports downloading the recorded audio but not directly returning audio data to streamlit/Python.

[image: screenshot of component]