# How to get Wav instead of Ogg using Web Audi API?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I developed some web pages (HTML, PHP and VanillaJS) dealing with sound samples with Web Audio API. Everything works fine even if this was a bit challenging for me.

After some treatments of the samples, the goal is to save 1 to 4 samples files in one. I achieved it but the only issue I met is the fact that I'm unable to get merged samples in Wav format but always in OGG format.
Ok, this is not so annoying but I'm not working for me but for somebody who is totally ignorant in term of sound file and would like to be able to play the file without the need of any extra software, so WAV format is a kind of standard for him.

I searched but didn't find any solution. Hereunder is a part of the code I use to initialize :

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const context = new AudioContext();    
var destRec = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(destRec.stream);
```

Once all the process done :

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(evt) {
// Make blob out of our blobs
var blob = new Blob(chunks, {'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'});
//then the rest of the process to save the file...
}
```

In the posted code I used 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' but I've tried with other options like 'audio:wav' but it doesn't work.

So, is it a "normal" behavior or did I missed something ?
Another solution would be to keep the OGG file and then convert it to WAV. I also tried that using FFmpeg but this is another story/nightmare that I'll develop in another post if this is the only solution I have.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the intermediate lossy compression you can try to run `decodeAudioData()` with the `Blob`.

Something like this should work:

```js
const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(await blob.arrayBuffer());
```

It will produce an `AudioBuffer` which allows you to access the PCM data.

However as the author of a package which extends the native `MediaRecorder` to support wav recordings I do of course recommend using that. The package is called [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder). Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191193/media-recorder-save-in-wav-format-across-browsers) for a quick example on how to use it.